# what is the reason for the difference between setprecision (12) and setprecision (012) for example,in c++?

Tags: c++, octal

In c++ when you write setprecision (12) for example, 12 is in the base of 10 but when you write it like setprecision (012) it is an octal number,why?

Comment: Because that's how it is in C and C++. There is no other answer. Integral literals beginning with `0` are octal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because constants with leading zeros (other than leading 0x) are always octal:

> An octal integer literal (base eight)
>   begins with the digit 0 and consists
>   of a sequence of octal digits.

C++ draft standard ([n1905](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)) §2.13.1

It has nothing at all to do with setprecision.

Comment: @Ehsan: click the checkmark next to the answer to officially say that.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's how it worked in C.  Back when C was designed, octal numbers were in frequent use, so they put in a notation for them.  Currently, it's rarely helpful and mostly confusing.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, if an integer literal begins with a `0` digit (and that `0` is not followed by a `x`), the following digits are treated as octal digits.