# Why is the number understood in hectadecimal?

Tags: c++

In C++ if you do cout << 47, it prints 47 but if you do cout << 047, it prints 39, which is 47 in hectadecimal. Why is that? Why does the compiler turn it into hectadecimal if you place no matter how many zeroes before a number. Is this a convention?

Comment: `047` is 39 written in octal. in `C` and `C++`, numbers starting with a `0` digit are octal (base 8). (And you mean "hexadecimal" (base 16) not "hectadecimal" :))

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the reason for the difference between setprecision (12) and setprecision (012) for example,in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740715/what-is-the-reason-for-the-difference-between-setprecision-12-and-setprecision/2740721#2740721)

Comment: what is hectadecimal?  is it base 110?

Comment: no i meant hecta* , i know hexa is 16, i thought that would be the right way to say it. sexta septa, hecta

Comment: It's octal, not hectadecimal.

Comment: Why do so many people here fiercely try to find duplicates, looking for the smallest resemblance?

Comment: @uagamaga Oops, sorry! Please revert my last edit ...

Comment: fyi, `cout << 16 << 0x10 << 020` will output the integer 16 as a decimal number 3 times to `cout`.  The C++ language's integer constant representation format is not known by cout, it's just 3 different ASCII formats for representing the integer 16.

Comment: @franji1:  Actually, the compiler will convert the values to the same internal base and pass them to the formatting routine.

Answer (score 6):

The leading '0' indicates the number is octal.

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int, char ** )
{
std::cout << 0x10 << std::endl;
std::cout << 020 << std::endl;
std::cout << 16 << std::endl;

return( 0 );
}
```

All produce an output of 16.  The numbers are literals that all have the same value.

Comment: It's not the streaming operator that understands that. The streaming operator `<<` just sees a number. The *compiler* determines that the integer constant `047` is in octal and creates a value accordingly.

Comment: @EricFinn: The compiler has no choice in this matter. The lexical rules of language prescribe this behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, I didn't mean to imply otherwise. I was simply trying to emphasize that `operator<<` has absolutely nothing to do with how the literal `047` is interpreted.

Comment: @EricFinn: Sure. Today I'm on a crusade to weed out the pure thought from the impure thought, striving to prune everything that isn't relevant and distracting the student who seeks enlightenment, not entanglement :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you prefix your numbers with a `0`, it will be in octal, or base 8.

If you prefix your numbers with `0x` it will be in hexadecimal, or base 16.

<sub>I don't know that the prefix for 'hectadecimal'(base 110) is, I don't think there is one</sub>